# Best CMS for muliti-language and accessibility?

Tags: cms, localization, accessibility

I’m helping an organization that works with people who come to this country (Sweden) understanding different languages (including right-to-left) and some who are disabled (difficulties to see for example).

I’m going to build a new website for them and I was wondering which CMS you would recommend for multi-language and accessibility?

Since we will also have need for other (more regular) features, and an admin interface that is easy to use, the main alternatives I see are WordPress, Drupal 8 and Joomla. I’ve read that Drupal 8 has improvements in these areas so if going with Drupal it would be 8 and not 7. I also understand that Joomla has built-in support for multiple languages.

Which CMS would you recommend?

Comment: A good question. Which I won't attempt to answer. I will just point out that http://www.cmsmatrix.org/ is the "got o" site for any CMS selection decisions.

Comment: *What I've looked at so far* And what were the outcomes? Where did they fit or not? Why are you mentioning them? Do not make us repeat your investigations. And can you [edit] your question in an attempt to make it less broad? Price, OS, what disabilitries exactly, what content are you going to have, .....

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. To give good answers, we need to know your requirements better – as Jan already pointed out.